# Change the size of existing UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I have a `UILabel`. Its name, size and other properties are set in IB.
I wish to change the font size if the text is longer than lets say 100.

All the examples I saw here I have to supply the text name but I'm looking for something of the sort:

```
label.font.size = 15;
```

I can't user `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0f]]` nor `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]`
I'm sure there must be a way to change only the size

Answer (score 3):

```
label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:15];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:label.font.familyName size:15];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `minimumFontSize` and `minimumScaleFactor` depending on which versions of iOS you need to support.